# How do I restart a Wowza application from within a module?

Tags: java, wowza

I want to restart the wowza application, from a module by which i no need to go to the services to restart the wowza service. If its possible please give a better solution or is there any method to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `IApplicationInstance.shutdown(isServerShutdown, isAppShutdown)` or `IApplication().shutdown(isServerShutdown)` in your module or HTTPProvider. In your HTTPProvider, you would need to get a reference to the application instance that you would like to shutdown.

Comment: ok, but I need to restart the to restart the service, so is there any way to do that based on some condition. It means if i set a boolean variable and if it comes true then i need to restart the service else not. Is it possible to do using any code to be added in the wowza custom module

Comment: Since Wowza runs on JVM, you would be referring to restarting the JVM service. It is not really good practice to do this from within the Java application. Best method is to restart the VHost. You can do so by calling the `shutdown()` method on the IVHost object. Alternatively, you can use a third-party tool such as Monit to restart the OS service.